# How can I edit google-service.json file for google login in android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am working on android app , by mistake I entered wrong sha key in google developer console while registering for google sign in enable, now I want to fix google-service.json file. So, is there any way I can edit the file from google developer console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this link witch helps you start integrating google services with your app :

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In

if it doesn't open please open it from the following documentation page ( which is the reference ) :

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

hit the get configuration file button

good luck !

Comment: I already have google-service.json file, I want to modify sha key inside it, how can I do that?

Comment: you can open and edit google-services-json from android studio files tree ( in the project files view ) ... you can find it in the folder named app..

Comment: however edits in this file will not be updated on google cloud console !!

Comment: is there any way, I can update google-service.json on server

Comment: By following that link you can update or creat new services configurations .. and once you are done you will be prompted to download the new Google - services. Json file

Comment: You also can edit yor app fingertip in google clo2 console and redo that step in the json file inside your app .. the former way is easier